# Get the filtered activedirectoryclient.users from azure adfs using like

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365, adfs

I am trying to get few users from Azure ADFS within my domain. I am able to get all of my users from my integrated Office 365. But my requirement is to get the filtered user lists. Can we do something like below, I have tried. But it doesn't return anything even if I have few users with that.

```
ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
                      async () => await GetTokenForApplication());
var result0 = await activeDirectoryClient.Users
              .Where(u => u.GivenName.Contains("sibeesh"))
              .ExecuteAsync();

var result1 = await activeDirectoryClient.Users
                  .Where(u => SqlMethods.Like(u.DisplayName, "sib%"))
                  .ExecuteAsync();
```

And also how can we get the users from other domains which we have in our ADFS? How can we group those users accordingly. I am totally new to configuring ADFS, any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get the terms right.

There is no such thing as Azure ADFS.

Azure AD is in the cloud. ADFS is on-premises and is not an Azure product.

You are using the Azure AD Graph API Client Library and there are some good examples of syntax [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2014/12/11/announcing-azure-ad-graph-api-client-library-2-0/).

This client library does not talk to ADFS.

Azure AD does not have the concept of domains - rather tenants.

Please clarify "And also how can we get the users from other domains which we have in our ADFS?"